# Datetimevalue function adding an hour

Tags: formula, custom-field, datetime

I’m using the Datetimevalue function in a formula field to convert a date value to a date time and it’s saving on the record as 00:00 GMT as expected, however when viewing it it is converting to 01:00 despite the fact the company and user time zone are set to GMT +0.

Comment: Consider that you may be in a timezone that applies DST and that the date you set is in the DST part of the year. E.g. Europe/London, which looks like GMT+00:00 in winter.